# Restler setup not working

Tags: apache, restler

On my webserver running `Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.4.24 mod_ssl/2.2.26 OpenSSL/0.9.8y` I am trying to setup Restler but it can't seem to handle the index.php properly.  This is a webapp setup with an httpd.conf that looks like so:

```
Alias "/dts2" "/usr/local/WebApps/DTS/root"

<Directory "/usr/local/WebApps/DTS/root">
  AllowOverride All
  Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
```

So then I went into that 'root' directory and ran this command to install restler:

`composer create-project restler/application=dev-basic api --prefer-dist`

After that, in the 'api' directory I created my .htaccess file that looks like so:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^$ public/index.php [QSA,L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_flag display_errors On
</IfModule>
```

And, finally when I try to access "https://..../dts2/api/Home/" to get the success message that restler provides, I get a 404 error.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: this seems more related to Apache than Restler. I would suggest changing the tags.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure it is.  If I look at the rewrite rules, and the path shown on the 404, it's the URL to the index.php, so I think the thing Restler tries to then load is what is really getting the 404 returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, finally got this working.  There were two issues.

One was Restler itself.  The supplied index.php said `$r->addAPIClass('Home', '');`.  I had to remove that second empty parameter.

The other was apache.   Instead of saying `public/index.php` on the RewriteRule I had to say `/dts2/api/public/index.php`.

Once I made those two changes everything worked as expected.